# Question about proof of sum of the n numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, intuition

watching a proof for the sums of n number we have we have that:

$$(n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n +1$$

how does that latter equation becomes

$$(n+1)^2 - 1^2 =2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k + n $$

I know there are better proofs but I would like to see the explanation of this one because if I understand this I can derive the next proof  of sums of squares

Comment: We know that $\sum_{k=1}^nk=(n^2+n)/2$. A simple calculation gives you the equality of the second equation.

Comment: It is a telescoping series. Write out $ [ (n+1)^2 - n^2] + [n^2 - (n-1)^2] + \ldots + [2^2 - 1^2] = [2n+1] + [2(n-1) + 1] + \ldots + [2\times1 + 1]$.

Comment: @CalvinLin all the terms cancel out on the left except for (n+1)^2 and -1^2

Comment: @CalvinLin on the right you factor out the 2 and n + n-1 .. becomes the sum and 1+1+1.. becomes n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd handle it as a telescoping sum.

Or if you're not yet comfortable with that, write it out $n$ times, for $n, n-1, n-2, ... 1$:

$$ 
\begin{align}
(n+1)^2 - (n-0)^2 &= 2(n-0) +1\\
(n-0)^2 - (n-1)^2 &= 2(n-1) +1\\
(n-1)^2 - (n-2)^2 &= 2(n-2) +1\\
(n-2)^2 - (n-3)^2 &= 2(n-3) +1\\
(n-3)^2 - (n-4)^2 &= 2(n-4) +1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
2^2 -1^2 &= 2(1) +1
\end{align}$$

and then add them all up and enjoy all the cancellations that happen on the left hand side.

(This is really just what a telescoping sum is, but writing out *all* of the details.)